# gtkmm tree like one in win32

Tags: gtktreeview, gtkmm3

I try to implement tree like in windows explorer using gtkmm3.

My problem is that to add icon I add a column for it, so it look strange [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI9il.png) :
 * The tree triangle and dot line is on the left
 * All text label is aligned on there row on the right.
 * And icon are floating between us aligned on the left
=> See attached image for more details...

My goal it to have text not aligned on a row but following the icon with a fixed width.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: The link to the image is : https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI9il.png

Answer (score 0):

Self-service : solution is here : https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-treeview.html.en - 9.2.3. More than one Model Column per View Column
=> Who said that there's no documentation...

1 - Create a Gtk::TreeView::Column
2 - Add column with icon
  * fct : column->pack_start ( put your column id here, false );  <= false (no padding)
  * Model : Gtk::TreeModelColumn
3 - Add column with text
  * fct : column->pack_start ( put your column id here, true );   <= true (padding)
  * Model : Gtk::TreeModelColumn
4 - Add colun to tree : tree->append_column ( column)
5 - set line icon and text
  * row[column text id] = "Billy Bob";
  * row[column icon id ] = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file ( "png path in my case" );

Warning icon size is 1:1 to adjust size you need to add more code. In my case i use svg so i can build the pix with the right size...

Tips : To hide header : tree->set_headers_visible ( false );